# Can I use a ListView inside another ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to design my app. with more modularity. In my app most of the screens are `ListView`s, and with similar list items.

For eg. I have 3 `ListView`s, each for a different category. (Music list, Audi list, Video list) and 1 Main view, that list latest 2 list items of each category.

My Plan is to reuse the 3 inner `ListView`s on my Main view as as list items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a multi-list view (each item having or not a subitem), you can use an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if that's possible but the first thing I would try is an `ExpandableList`.

Check this so question:

- [How to add image in expandable List in parent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353101/119895)