# layout as listview header

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a layout that contains two lists. Since you can't put lists in a `ScrollView` I am trying to use an `ExpandableListView`, with a custom `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/about-expandable-list-in-android).
List layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the troubles come when I try to add something as header. It works if I create a layout from code, like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout( this );
ll.setOrientation( LinearLayout.VERTICAL );
TextView t = new TextView( this );
t.setText( "some text" );
ll.addView( t );
ImageView i = new ImageView( this );
i.setImageResource( R.drawable.icon );
ll.addView( i );
getExpandableListView( ).addHeaderView( ll );
```

If I use the same layout, or simpler even than the one from code, the application crashes before even showing on screen. Here's the layout I want to add as header to the above list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"/>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.ll );
getExpandableListView( ).addHeaderView( ll );
```

I tried to fiddle with the layout_width or height of about all the components in my layout, but it doesn't work. What baffles me most is that when it crashes, on the DDMS says `NullPointerException` when calling setAdapter (which doesn't when I use the layout from code, and it adds the adapter just fine):

```
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.stephan.test/org.stephan.test.ExpandableListViewTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2833)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:506)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:492)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:424)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:475)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.setListAdapter(ExpandableListActivity.java:246)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at org.stephan.test.ExpandableListViewTest.onCreate(ExpandableListViewTest.java:80)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1066)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
01-16 01:17:27.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21314):     ... 11 more
```

So, my question is: what am I doing wrong here? And, in case, any advices on how I could do this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of creating a new layout with
`LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.ll );`
you need to inflate it! The following does the trick:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );  
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.ll, null, false );
getExpandableListView( ).addHeaderView( ll );
```

Where ll.xml is the layout you intend to attach to the list as a header. Hope this helps someone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ExpandableListActivity has a default
>   layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen, centered expandable list.
>   However, if you desire, you can
>   customize the screen layout by setting
>   your own view layout with
>   setContentView() in onCreate(). To do
>   this, your own view MUST contain an
>   ExpandableListView object with the id
>   "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in
>   code)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html

So, in your custom layout, change the id from `ll` to `@android:id/list`. Also, call `setContentView` with your custom layout file.

I didn't understand quite well what you intended to do but as soon as you explain it better, I might help you further. (The way I see it, it seems that you want to get the list view and then add that list view to its header... weird)

**EDIT:**

just try to use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    </LinearLayout>

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"

               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for replying. What I want to achieve is: in one layout I have the ExpListView correctly set up with the id you say. What I want to do is to add a separate layout as the list header. will edit my question to show the list layout as well.

Comment: Is the other layout static? If so, you have a much simpler solution. Also, are you using expanding layout because you need it to list your 'things' or, for some reason, you think you need this to put the two layouts together?

Comment: The header layout will be filled dynamically, based on data I receive, so it can't be static (if by 'static' you mean put data in the xml). I am using the expanding layout because I have two different lists and I was thinking that in this way I can use different layouts for the subgroups. Then, since I want that famous header to scroll with the list, it came natural to think it as the header. But I've been stuck on this for 3 days now, so I'm open to suggestions! :)

Comment: Now I receive this: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams where I do setListAdapter(new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(...)).

Comment: Instead of `ListView` in the layout I gave you, have it `ExpandableListView`

Comment: It already is, I just added the "empty" TextView and moved the 'header' layout into this one, as you suggested. EDIT: removing the "addHeaderView" call makes it work, but the 'header' is fixed, while I'd like it to scroll with the list.