# How to add different component types in ExpandableListView subelements

Tags: android, expandablelistview

SA,

I've used the example found here:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html

to have checkboxes as sub components for ExpandableListView.

The problem is, I need to have the following structure:

```
-Main Item 1
   - text   checkbox
   - text   checkbox
   - button
-Main Item 2
   - text   checkbox
   - text   checkbox
   - button
-Main Item 3
   - text   checkbox
   - text   checkbox
   - button
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well this is not the answer that you want, But I am sure you will get to know much about how to do that. [Exapdable with Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/about-expandable-list-in-android)