# How to overcome this problem with using more listviews in a layout

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using 4 listviews in my layout and if i use scrollview , i cannot scroll into my listview. If i remove scrollview in my xml, then the last list is been hiddden. How to overcome this problem?

My code goes below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout android:id="@id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="42.0dip">
    <Button android:textSize="23.0dip" android:onClick="newtodo_Click" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/btnNewTodo" android:background="@drawable/new_todo" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#FF0000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="High Priority" android:id="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvhigh" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:background="#000000" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="175px"></ListView>
<TextView android:background="#ffff01" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Medium Priority" android:id="@+id/textView2"></TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvmed" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="175px"></ListView>
<TextView android:background="#00ff01" android:textColor="#000000"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Low Priority" android:id="@+id/textView3"></TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvlow" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="175px"></ListView>
<TextView android:background="#cccccc" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Incomplete Tasks" android:id="@+id/textView4"></TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvinc" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="175px"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any Help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use wrap_content for the height of each listview. would something smaller still be ok?

Comment: I think its just bad design, u should have just one listview in your app and at max two but having 4 is just insane. I am not sure if ur app can really convey much information to the user with such an interface. BTW scrollView will not work if it has a listview in it.

Comment: Instead of wrap content, Is this right way to give values in pixels/dp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An simple workaround is to

1. Remove `ScrollView`
2. Set height of all `ListView` to 0
3. Set `layout_weight` property of all child to 1

Answer (score 2):

In you layout there is textview and after that listview so why you not used expandable listVIew.It will help you in your problem.

Here is example of Expandable listview

[Expandable Listview](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html)

[Expandable Listview example](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/about-expandable-list-in-android)

[Click Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

Comment: Since i'm new to android, i m searching off to the best way... Is there any referred link to use Expandable listview?

Answer (score 1):

To overcome, try re-factoring your UI to not include multiple scrollable objects inside of another scrollable object. This will not be reliable and will produce unexpected results (as you have found).

As the100rabh said, this is generally bad design. Normally an application will present a list of some sort to a user. Four lists for a screen that is 2-5 (~10 for tablets) inches is three too many.

Answer (score 1):

please set your listview as a non scrolling container By using

```
ls_edu.setScrollContainer(false);
```

it may help to scroll the list view.