# How can i show image in childgroup in expandablelistview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am able to show text in childgroup in but i am unable to show image in particular childgroup.

plz help

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out this your query is answered here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/about-expandable-list-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think this is useful for you...

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view= getGenericGroupView(groupPosition ,convertView);
    return view;

    }           
    public View getGenericGroupView(int groupPosition, View convertView) {
                    // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
                    View view=null;
                    try{


                    AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 90);
                    view=convertView;
                    Holder holder=new Holder(); 
                    if(convertView==null)
                    {
                        LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater) ExpandableList1.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
                        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

                        view.setPadding(80, 5, 5, 5);
                        holder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);

                        view.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder=(Holder) view.getTag();
                    }
                        holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);


                    }catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                    return view;
                }
        private class Holder
                {
        private ImageView image;
        }
```