# Changing backgroundcolor in listview (expandable listview)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to dynamically change a backgroundcolor in a part of a listview, I have on example that works fine in a listview when I try to replicate it in another part with an expandable listview it fails

This piece of code works and displays a different color if a student is online or not

...

```
map.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, temp.firstName);
map.put(KEY_NAME, temp.name);
map.put(KEY_EMAIL, temp.email);
map.put(KEY_ISONLINE, temp.isOnLine);

// change image if student is online or not
Log.d("demo", "is on line= " + temp.isOnLine);
if (temp.isOnLine.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    map.put(KEY_IMAGE_ISONLINE, R.color.greenColor);
} else {
    map.put(KEY_IMAGE_ISONLINE, R.color.greyColor);
}
listItem.add(map);
}
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTabLeerlingen);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(StudentTab.this,
    listItem,
    R.layout.list_item_student,
    new String[] { KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_NAME,
    KEY_IMAGE_ISONLINE }, new int[] {
    R.id.firstNameTextView,
    R.id.lastNameTextView,
    R.id.logo });
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the xml that goes along with it

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/greenColor"
            android:contentDescription="Image if student is online or not"
            android:src="@drawable/transparent_pixel" />
```

The above works fine however the following code (just part of the code)

...

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < _data.length(); i++) {
try {   
   JSONArray tmp = _data.getJSONArray(i);
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // change image if student is online or not
    if (tmp.getString(3).equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        map.put(KEY_POINTS,R.color.redColor);
    }else{
        map.put(KEY_POINTS,R.color.greenColor);
    }
        map.put(KEY_QUESTIONTEXT, tmp.getString(1)); 
        map.put(KEY_ANSWER, tmp.getString(2));
        children.add(map);
    } 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
childData.add(children);
```

...

...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>> childData) {
            SimpleExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                    this, groupData, R.layout.list_item_results_students,
                    new String[] { KEY_FIRSTNAME, KEY_NAME, KEY_ISJUIST },
                    new int[] { R.id.firstnameResults, R.id.nameResults,
                            R.id.resultsTextView }, childData,
                    R.layout.list_item_results_results, new String[] {
                            KEY_QUESTIONTEXT, KEY_ANSWER, KEY_POINTS }, new int[] {
                            R.id.questionTextView, R.id.answerTextTextView, R.id.score });
            ExpandableListView myListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTabResultaten);
            myListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

with xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/greenColor"
        android:contentDescription="Image if student has correct answer"
        android:src="@drawable/transparent_pixel" />
```

I will get this error:

06-09 10:35:21.490: E/AndroidRuntime(4406): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` states

> childTo   The child views that should display column in the "childFrom"
>   parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this
>   list are given the values of the first N columns in the childFrom
>   parameter.

So the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` only accepts the `TextView` class.
The documentation states the same for `SimpleAdapter`, but looking at the source code (eg. [SimpleAdapter.bindView()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#SimpleAdapter.bindView)) you can see that they also check for `ImageView` and other types.

Therefore your first example worked but the second one throws the `ClassCastException`.

To fix it you could override `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` behavior like shown in this older [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353101/about-expandable-list-in-android)

Comment: It seems all answer are the same but this one gave me a solution,  I just couldn't understand why the simpleadapter accepted the imageview.  Thanks

Comment: I managed to get it working following the url you provided.  I can set a custom image depending on a condition however like in my first example I would like to pass in a background-color instead of an image.  How can that be achieved?

Comment: Ok just found it myself: .setBackgroundDrawable( (Drawable) ... works great

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for SimpleExpandableListAdapter the childTo argument contains your ImageView item, @+id/score.  The childTo array should contain only TextViews.  You are trying to assign a color int to an image.

[SimpleExpandableListAdapter Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html#SimpleExpandableListAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

The same is actually true for your SimpleAdapter above where you use @+id/logo.

[Simple Adapter Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters

context The context where the ExpandableListView associated with this SimpleExpandableListAdapter is running
groupData   A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one group in the list. The Maps contain the data for each group, and should include all the entries specified in "groupFrom"
groupLayout resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for a group. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "groupTo"
groupFrom   A list of keys that will be fetched from the Map associated with each group.
groupTo The group views that should display column in the "groupFrom" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the groupFrom parameter.
childData   A List of List of Maps. Each entry in the outer List corresponds to a group (index by group position), each entry in the inner List corresponds to a child within the group (index by child position), and the Map corresponds to the data for a child (index by values in the childFrom array). The Map contains the data for each child, and should include all the entries specified in "childFrom"
childLayout resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for a child. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "childTo"
childFrom   A list of keys that will be fetched from the Map associated with each child.
**childTo   The child views that should display column in the "childFrom" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the childFrom parameter.**

in the source code of SimpleExpandableListAdapter.java you will find that:

private void bindView(View view, Map data, String[] from, int[] to) {
        int len = to.length;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(to[i]);
        if (v != null) {
            v.setText((String)data.get(from[i]));
        }
    }
}
```